# Get a list of duplicated objects, including all occurrences C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class `MyClass`

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string ITEM1 { set; get; }
    public string ITEM2 { set; get; }
}
```

And a list

```
List<MyClass> listMyClass = new List<MyClass>();
```

with 3 objects

```
  {1, "APPLE", "LIME"}
  {1, "LIME", "APPLE"}
  {2, "ORANGE", "LEMON"}
```

I would like to exclude non-duplicated objects BUT if there are 2 duplicated object, I want to list them all. So the result list I would like to have

```
  {1, "APPLE", "LIME"}
  {1, "LIME", "APPLE"}
```

I try

```
  var dupes = .GroupBy(g => g.ID).SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1)).ToList();
```

This only gives me

```
  {1, "APPLE", "LIME"}
```

Pleas ignore the reason why I have objects with same ID but have different contents. How could I get a full list of duplicated objects?

Comment: I think you dont want to skip 1 if there's a duplicate

Comment: You want to group by ID but then loop through the grouping and check if the group count is greater than 1.

Comment: @Broom, if I don't have Skip then I have a list of everything, including non-duplicated ones.

Comment: yeah, but it's also skipping the first copy of the duplicated groups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var dupes = listMyClass.GroupBy(i => i.ID).Where(i => i.Count() > 1).SelectMany(i => i).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
var dupes = listMyClass.GroupBy(g => g.ID).SelectMany(grp => grp.Count() <= 1 ? new MyClass[] { } : grp.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Comment: eh, nvm, Ringil's is cleaner